# How might a person summon the devil from its prison?

Tags: physics, medieval, quantum, supernatural, prophecy

A society of prophets live according to middle-age superstitions. They abide by a lunar calendar, put a strong emphasis on star signs, and believe they possess psychic powers such as palm reading and crystal gazing. They are NOT sorcerers; they can time travel and visit alternate realities but this is explained by quantum physics, not magic. They do have dark powers like necromancy, but they believe that these powers are granted by the devil, a supernatural being that resides in the sun. So how might such a society bring down the devil? I’m looking for a psychic or quantum physics explanation, not a magic one.

Clarification: When I say “bring down the devil,” I mean calling him down to persuade society to do evil. According to the legends of this society, the devil’s powers have been restricted by ancient prophets who confined him to the sun. However, a prophet can release the devil by trading places with him. Supposing a prophet wanted to unleash the devil’s powers, how might they trade places with him? Since the protagonist possesses supernatural powers, I’m willing to bend the rules of quantum physics, I just don’t want an entirely handwaving explanation.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Are you looking for a liturgical explanation or purely scientific?  If the former, which religion are you wanting?  If the latter, I think it's too exclusive for a natural explanation.  Just asking for clarification.

Comment: I assume this is the devil as portrayed in Christianity and Islam? Without knowledge of the specific portrayal, it's difficult to give a good answer

Comment: What abilities does the devil have that allow them to not die? Can they just go up to the devil and punch them to death?

Comment: Does "bring down the devil" mean get the devil to come down from the sun and visit, or conquer and defeat the devil?  A problem with "the devil" as you use the term  is that clearly this is not Satan from the Book of Job; it is some other entity called "devil" that lives in the sun and grants quantum physics powers.  Its motivations are unclear.   The other definition I struggle with is how you do not want magic, yet magical feats like dimensional travel is quantum physics in your world, and the devil is called supernatural - but grants powers based on quantum physics?  More background needed.

Comment: You have no problems with time travel, but teleportation bothers you? Just have them able to teleport to exchange their position with the devil.

Comment: It's at present very unclear what you're after here. Please clarify the rules of your world and the exact nature an capabilities of your "devil" - lest the question be closed as unclear. Middle ages covers a vast period in history when nobody knew about quantum mechanics, please clarify what it is you're after and what you're up-against.

Comment: @Willk, @A Rogue Ant. - It seems that more detail and/or background is required to answer the question. I haven't fully explored this society yet so I can't provide more information at the time, but I'll definitely keep these points in mind as I write. I may clarify the question at a later time; as of now I've chosen not to delete it because I've found the answers useful and others may find them helpful as well. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer because it contains neither psychic nor quantum physics aspects, but some aspects of the ritual can be defined by the involvement of the Sun.

When perceived from a terrestrial point of view, the sun waxes and wains across the passage of the day.  There is a mid-afternoon moment when the sun appears to be at its strongest.  For most of the night, it appears to be weakest.  At both dawn and twilight, spectacular changes occur.

So, since the sun is a prison in your setting, those four moments in the day might correlate to states of the prison.  Noon could be lock-down and nighttime could be its regular, low-security operating mode.  This leaves dawn and dusk to be your chaotic, moments of opportunity, the changing of the guards.

If I were planning a jail break, I would do it (perform the ritual) during the changing of the guard.

Answer (score 1):

Quote opening: *"A society of prophets live according to middle-age superstitions."*

In case of being a *prophet* you'll have a direct line with any aetheric being,  the devil included.. Bringing down the devil is easy, just  invite it for dinner. I'm sure the devil will find it worth while to show up. There's no wine in the sun and prophets are susceptible humans, they can be influenced easily by any story the devil would like to make up to deceive them. One good hallucination will cause prophets to go spread messages around.

Answer (score 0):

They can indeed swap places with them, it's simple.

Step 1. Time travel to before the sun existed.

Step 2. Time travel to the devil's prison, avoiding the flaming death of the sun. Swap with them.

Step 3. Have a second prophet who has traveled to before the sun existed swap places with the devil. They will burn in the fires of the sun, and the devil will now be several billion years in the past. The timing of this will be tight, since the prophet will instantly die within the sun.

Step 4. Have a third prophet time travel back to grab the devil and bring them back to normal society.